# How do you find whether two 2-dimensional arrays(or matrices) are same?(only you can do interchange row operation or interchange column operation)

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to prove that these two matrices have a mapping:

a:{{0 2 3 1},{2 0 3 1},{3 3 0 4},{1 1 4 0}}
  b:{{0 4 3 3},{4 0 1 1},{3 1 0 2},{3 1 2 0}}

As you can see by interchanging rows and columns i can obtain the second matrix from the first but i don't how how to code this in java or c. Please help me out. The matrices are taken as two dimensional arrays a[4][4] and b[4][4] respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the first matrix and store the result in a map. In the map. The key can be the sorted rows in the matrix, and the values should be the count of occurrence of the corresponding key. So for matrix a, the resulted map should be {[0 1 2 3] -> 2, [0 1 1 4] -> 1, [0 3 3 4] -> 1}

Then, you can either 
1) parse the second matrix and stores the result in another map in the same way, and then compare the two maps. or

2) for each sorted row in b, find the key value pair in the map corresponding to a, and decrease the value of that key by 1. If some key is not in the map, or some value is decreased to -1, return false; otherwise return true after checking each row in b.

EDIT:

```
public static boolean matrixEqual(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    Map<Integer[], Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer[], Integer>();
    int sizeA = a.length;
    // maybe compare sizeA and sizeB here
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
        // int[] temp = sorted a[i];
        // if (temp not a key in m) m.put(temp, 1);
        // else m.put(temp, previousvalue + 1);
    }
    int sizeB = b.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeB; i++) {
        // int[] temp = sorted b[i];
        // if (temp not a key in m) return false;
        // else if (m.get(temp) == 0) return false;
        // else m.put(temp, previousvalue - 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: could you provide the java code to do this. would be of great help. thanks.

Comment: Please provide me with code as i have an assignment due and i find it very tough to do this

Comment: @user3221188 i would rather not doing your homework. i just provided you some skeleton code. now it is time to google around and show your effort.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.Tony ....just one thing i would like to know .....i am not able to do m.put(temp,value) as there is an error that int cannot be converted to Integer(incompatible types) ....how to resolve this???